# child script eval and ${@} differences

Tags: bash, shell, expansion

I have a parent script

```
while read cmd 
do
  nohup ./script ${cmd[@]} &>> log &
done < ~/list
```

that executes this child script

```
while true
do 
  eval "${CMD[@]}"
  #${CMD[@]}
  #./panic
done
```

with this list of commands

```
node ~/www/splash/app.js
node ~/www/splash-two/app.js
```

When the child script calls 
  
 `eval ${CMD[@]}`
it executes the way I expect running that command with no complaints but when I try to remove the eval and run the command using 
  
`${CMD[@]}`
It throws the error

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/rumplefraggle/SYS/RABBOT/~/www/splash/app.js'
```

Now I thought possibly this had something to do with the node command so I tried to execute 

`ls ~`

as the command and it throws the error that ~ can not be found.


Echoing ${@} and not running it expands as I would expect it to.

Also manually inserting the command into the child script also works as expected

I don`t understand why eval works and simply running the command using ${@} does not. What is causing ${@} to not expand the ~ ?
Why is node appending the directory name to the command when ${@} is used?

Answer (score 2):

Because bash first expands tilde and then the variables. `node` is not the one expanding the variable. You should stick with `eval` or use `${HOME}` in your commands.

[The expansion order is like this](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions): brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter, variable, and arithmetic expansion and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion), word splitting, and filename expansion

Comment: Why does it expand the way I expect when I use eval?

Comment: The shell expands the variable first so that eval can see the contents. Then eval executes it, which causes a second expansion.